# How to conditionally call tracing-subscriber methods?

Tags: rust, rust-tracing

I'm trying to setup [tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) and I have this code but it compiles with errors:

```rust
use tracing_subscriber;

pub fn init(is_pretty: bool) {
    let subscriber = tracing_subscriber::fmt();
    if is_pretty {
        &subscriber.pretty();
    }
    subscriber.init();
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `subscriber`
   --> src\main.rs:8:5
    |
4   |     let subscriber = tracing_subscriber::fmt();
    |         ---------- move occurs because `subscriber` has type `SubscriberBuilder`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
5   |     if is_pretty {
6   |         &subscriber.pretty();
    |                     -------- `subscriber` moved due to this method call
7   |     }
8   |     subscriber.init();
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

I tried this too but I get different compiler errors:

```rust
use tracing_subscriber;

pub fn init(is_pretty: bool) {
    let mut subscriber = tracing_subscriber::fmt();
    if is_pretty {
        subscriber = subscriber.pretty();
    }
    subscriber.init();
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src\main.rs:6:22
  |
4 |     let mut subscriber = tracing_subscriber::fmt();
  |                          ------------------------- expected due to this value
5 |     if is_pretty {
6 |         subscriber = subscriber.pretty();
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `DefaultFields`, found struct `Pretty`
  |
  = note: expected struct `SubscriberBuilder<DefaultFields, Format<tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::Full>>`
             found struct `SubscriberBuilder<Pretty, Format<Pretty>>`
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`SubscriberBuilder` encodes in its type the various options used to build the subscriber, so the only way to go would be:

```rust
if is_pretty {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter("info")
        .pretty()
        .init();
} else {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter("info")
        .init();
}
```

The fact is that this builder was probably thought to have "hard-coded" configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the second way but I still have issues: `mismatched types
expected struct `tracing_subscriber::fmt::SubscriberBuilder<tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::DefaultFields, tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::Format<tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::Full>, _>`
   found struct `tracing_subscriber::fmt::SubscriberBuilder<tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::Pretty, tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::Format<tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::Pretty>, _>`rustcE0308
tracing.rs(12, 26): expected due to this value`

Comment: If I try the first way you're suggesting the error is: `"if" and "else" have incompatible types rustc E0308`

Comment: @FredHors I updated my answer. There would be a way around to remove code duplication using traits, but I felt it's a bit overkill (it wouldn't reduce the amount of code written anyways), so I left it out.